# What is the equivalent of arView.scene.addAnchor() in ARSCNView?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I read [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/combining_user_face-tracking_and_world_tracking) officially provided by Apple.

There is the following code near line 150 of ViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARView!
let camera = AnchorEntity(.camera)
arView.scene.addAnchor(camera)
```

The above code works fine in ARView.
However, when I try to use addAnchor with ARSCNView, I get an error.

```
@IBOutlet weak var arSCNView: ARSCNView!
let camera = AnchorEntity(.camera)
arSCNView.scene.addAnchor(camera)
```

The details of the error are as follows.

```
Value of type 'SCNScene' has no member 'addAnchor'
```

I want to implement the equivalent of addAnchor in ARSCNView to get the value of `camera.transformMatrix (relativeTo: nil)`.

How can I do the same thing as `addAnchor (camera)` and `camera.transformMatrix (relativeTo: nil)` of ARView in ARSCNView?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview

> The ARSCNView class provides the easiest way to create augmented reality experiences that blend virtual 3D content with a device camera view of the real world. When you run the view's provided [ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession) object...

Use `add(anchor:)` instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2865612-add